# Exportar configurações da base de dados MySQL

Tags: mysql

Recentemente exportei uma base de dados `mysql` no formato `.sql`, entretanto algumas configurações não estão presentes, como por exemplo a configuração para `FULLTEXT index`.

Qual o procedimento correto para exportar esses tipos de configuração?

Comment: Tá fazendo a exportação por linha de comando ou por alguma aplicação?

Comment: @LINQ Eu fiz direto no phpadmin, mas pode ser por linha de comando também...